# Linking against hard-coded function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

I know that a particular function with a known signature is located at a known address. How do I initialise the function pointer in C++?

I have tried the following (and many variations thereof) to no avail:

```
int (*FunctionName)(int arg1, long arg2, char *arg3) = (int (*FunctionName)(int arg1, long arg2, char *arg3))0xCAKE;
```

I have a feeling it is the expression on the right hand side that is causing troubles, as the code will compile if it is initialised to `0x0` / `NULL`. Any pointers? (Pun intended).

Comment: Have you tried starting from a null pointer and then adding 0xCAKE/sizeof(functionpointer)?

Comment: Er, nevermind, do what CashCow said

Comment: You shouldn't be too sure that a function pointer is actually just an address. They can be structs, or pointers to structs where the compiler actually emits a little subroutine to load the jump target and go there. Pointers to class members is one example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx  . PowerPC function descriptors are another.

Comment: In all my frustration and mixing and matching of types, I pasted what appears to be clearly non-functional code. I accepted @CashCow's answer as it certainly clarifies the concept (as well as the code) for me and fits in my little mind. @Crashworks: That's interesting. Perhaps I should not be so hasty in making assumptions from now on!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the fact that CAKE is not a proper Hex value because K is not a valid hex character, plus any issues about different pointer types your main error is that FunctionName is a variable not a type.

It is like doing

`px = (px)0xBADFACE`;

where px is an regular pointer

If you remove FunctionName on the right leaving the rest it may work but easier would be a typedef.

```
typedef int( *FuncType)(int arg1, long arg2, char * arg3 );
FuncType FunctionName = (FuncType)(0xCAFE);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int (*FunctionName)(int arg1, long arg2, char *arg3) = (int ( * )(int arg1, long arg2, char *arg3))0x01;
```

Works in VS2008. FunctionName is the name of the variable and not part of the type.